# 2006 Equinox LS. Bottom Radiator hose is cold and no heat!

Tags: chevrolet, radiator, thermostat

I've changed the Thermostat in hopes that was the problem but after flushing the system and hooking everything back up the top Radiator hose is warm as usual but the bottom hose will warm up then minutes later its cold even if the car is running. Plus still no heat at all. What could cause this? Why does the bottom hose change temperatures so quick even while its running? What should i check next? Whereis the bleeder screw

Comment: First the easy thing after running the car with inside heater on for a while let car cool down and double check the radiator fill level as well as the overflow bottle to be sure that you didn't have an air bubble in the system.